# SAlvar em Binário

Tags: c

Gente, 
Tenho uma estrutura de 10 posições fixas. Cada uma delas tem um vetor cujo seu tamanho foi alocado dinamicamente. Estou tentando salvar em arquivo binario as informações e depois realizar a leitura do mesmo mas quando imprimo a leitura os dados aparecem em desordem. ALguém pode me ajudar ?

```
void terminar (principal *inicio){
    principal *temporario=inicio;
    principal *auxiliar=NULL;

    salvar_arquivo (inicio);

    for (temporario=inicio; temporario!=NULL; temporario=temporario->proximo){
        free (temporario->vetor);

        if (auxiliar!=NULL){
            free (temporario);
        }
        auxiliar=temporario;
    }

    if (auxiliar!=NULL){
        free (temporario);
    }

    exit (1);   
}

void salvar_arquivo (principal *inicio){
    FILE *arq;
    char tipo;

    do {
        printf ("Escolha um formato valido para salvar os dados (T/texto - B/binario):  ");
        scanf ("%s",&tipo);

        if (tipo == 'T'){
            arq = fopen ("trab2.txt","w");

                if (arq == NULL){
                    printf ("Erro ao tentar abrir o arquivo\n");
                    exit (1);
                } else              

            salvar_texto (inicio,arq);          
            fclose (arq);
        } 
        else {
                if (tipo == 'B'){
                    arq = fopen ("trab2.dat","wb");

                    if (arq == NULL){
                        printf ("Erro ao tentar abrir o arquivo\n");
                        exit (1);
                    } else 

                salvar_binario (inicio,arq);            
                fclose (arq);

                }
        }
    } while ((tipo!='T') && (tipo!='B'));

}

void salvar_texto (principal *inicio, FILE *arq){
    principal *aux_principal;

    for (aux_principal=inicio->proximo; aux_principal!=NULL; aux_principal=aux_principal->proximo){

        fprintf (arq, "\n%d,", aux_principal->tamanho);
        fprintf (arq, "%d,", aux_principal->numero);
        fprintf (arq, "%d,", aux_principal->fim);
        fprintf (arq, "%d;", aux_principal->posicao);

        for (int i=0; i<aux_principal->fim; i++){
            fprintf (arq, "%d;", aux_principal->vetor[i]);
        }

    }

}

void salvar_binario (principal *inicio, FILE *arq){
    principal *temp;

    for (temp=inicio->proximo; temp!=NULL; temp=temp->proximo){ 
        fwrite(&temp->tamanho, sizeof(principal), 1, arq);
        fwrite(&temp->numero, sizeof(principal), 1, arq);
        fwrite(&temp->fim, sizeof(principal), 1, arq);
        fwrite(&temp->posicao, sizeof(principal), 1, arq);

    //  fwrite(&temp->vetor, sizeof(int), temp->tamanho , arq);

        printf("SASASAS\n");
    } 

    printf ("\nArquivo salvo com sucesso !!");
}

void leitura_binario (principal *inicio,FILE *arq){
    principal *temp;

     while (!feof(arq)){
        temp = (principal*)malloc (sizeof( principal ));

        fread(temp, sizeof(principal), 1, arq);
        printf ("Tamanho: %d\n", temp->tamanho);
        printf ("numero: %d\n", temp->numero);
        printf ("posicao: %d\n", temp->posicao);

    }


    fclose (arq);
}

void leitura (principal *inicio){
    FILE *arq;
    char tipo;

    printf ("O arquivo gravado foi salvo em Binario ou Texto ? (B/Binario - T/Texto): ");
    scanf ("%c",&tipo);

    if (tipo == 'T'){
        arq = fopen ("trab2.txt","r");
        if (!arq){
            printf ("erro\n");
        }else leitura_texto (inicio,arq);
    } 
    else {
         if (tipo == 'B'){
            arq = fopen ("trab2.dat","rb");
        }
        if (!arq){
            printf ("erro\n");
        }else  leitura_binario (inicio,arq);
    }

}

void leitura_texto (principal *inicio,FILE *arq){
    principal *temp = inicio->proximo;

    if (arq == NULL){
            return;
    }

    for (temp=inicio->proximo; temp!=NULL; temp=temp->proximo){

        fscanf (arq, "\n%d,", &temp->tamanho);
        fscanf (arq, "%d,", &temp->numero);
        fscanf (arq, "%d,", &temp->fim);
        fscanf (arq, "%d;", &temp->posicao);

        if (temp->tamanho > 0){
             temp->vetor= (int *)malloc((temp->tamanho)*sizeof(int));  
             if (temp->vetor == NULL){
                    printf ("Memoria insuficiente\n");
             } else
                for (int i=0; i<temp->fim; i++){
                    fscanf (arq, "%d;", &temp->vetor[i]);
                }               
            }
    }

    fclose (arq);

}
```

Comment: Me parece que na escrita binária você salva campo a campo mas cada um deles no espaço equivalente a uma estrutura principal quando deveria gravar uma única vez mas toda a estrutura, que aliás você não mostrou qual é.

Comment: typedef struct estrutura {
 int tamanho;
 int numero;
 int *vetor;
 int fim;
 int posicao;
 struct estrutura *proximo;
} principal;

Comment: Eu até consegui salvar mas na hora da leitura é como se ele achasse a primeira posicao, fizesse a leitura corretamente e depois pegasse uns 6 lixos; acha a segunda, lê corretamente e mais lixo ... até a décima

Comment: Note que se você gravar a estrutura principal estará gravando um ponteiro para o vetor e não os elementos do vetor. Repense que dados deseja gravar no arquivo.

Comment: Segui sua dica de gravação e agora só lê as 10 posicoes (que é o tamanho da minha estrutura principal). Mas na impressão surge numeros descconhecidos e as informações não se encontram.

Comment: Impressao dos dados: 
posicao: 32764
Tamanho: -1766804848
numero: 21947
fim: -1676022528
posicao: 32764
Tamanho: -1766804800
numero: 21947
fim: -1676022528
posicao: 32764
Tamanho: -1766804752
numero: 21947
fim: -1676022528

Comment: Mas o ponteiro int * vetor continua válido quando você lê este endereço de  seu arquivo? Creio que você tenha que gravar em seu arquivo todos os elementos de seu vetor e não somente a estrutura principal.

Comment: Sim, você está correto. Deixei o vetor por ultimo por que  não consigo fazer o básico ainda

Comment: Como eu coloquei no primeiro comentário, aqui: fwrite(&temp->tamanho, sizeof(principal), 1, arq); você está gravando um int mas no espaço do tamanho de sua estrutura principal, mas na leitura espera ler neste espaço toda a estrutura.